# SQL replace statement too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a replace statement that does something like this:

```
SELECT Distinct Forenames, Surname, dbUSNs.DateOfBirth, Datasetname, 
       dbUSNs.MoPIGrade, SourceAddress, VRM, URNs 
FROM Person 
WHERE ( Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
        (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
        (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
        (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
        (Surname,'/',''''),'?',''''),'',''''),'^',''''),'{',''''),'}',''''),
                '[',''''),']',''''),';',''''),'$',''''),'=',''''),'*',''''),
                '#',''''),'|',''''),'&',''''),'@',''''),'\',''''),'<',''''),
                '>',''''),'(',''''),')',''''),'+',''''),',',''''),'.',''''),
                ' ','''') LIKE 'OREILLY%')
```

Therefore even though OReilly is passed, O'Reilly will be found.  However, this is too slow.  Is there a better way of approaching it?

Comment: What application is consuming the query? Ideally the handling of special characters needs to happen in the application - is there any good reason to do this in SQL?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta, yes I have retagged the question.

Comment: are you just looking to remove all special characters and leave only alpha numeric characters?

Comment: Try this function here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7044fab9-bdb2-4f54-98ed-7bcbaca3e648/how-to-remove-special-characters-in-a-particular-column?forum=transactsql We use it, and it is somewhat faster than replacing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't that `REPLACE` is "too slow", but that using it at all makes that part of the query *unsargable*, meaning that it can't use an index.

[Wikipedia: Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Basically you've forced a tablescan / indexscan, from top to bottom. On top of that you have the overhead of `REPLACE`.

If you want this query to run fast, I would instead do one of the following:

- Create an additional column containing a searchable text version of the Surname
- Create an indexed, materialized view with those REPLACE functions

Comment: Add to that that the output is a distinct, that adds to the overhead. This is one of the worst optimizable queries I have seen in my life. Not saying it makes no sense - business may dictate it - but for the database it is basically a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply remove all special characters it's easier to specify the valid characters and use a function to perform the cleansing.

This shows you how to clean the string to alphanumeric characters and spaces `'%[^a-z0-9 ]%'`

```
DECLARE @Temp nvarchar(max) ='O''Rielly la/.das.d,as/.d,a/.da.sdo23eu89038 !£$$'

SELECT @Temp

DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50) = '%[^a-z0-9 ]%'
WHILE PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    SET @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')
SELECT @Temp
```

Which would return: `ORielly ladasdasdadasdo23eu89038`

So you can write a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50) = '%[^a-z0-9 ]%'
    WHILE PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    RETURN @Temp
END
```

Then simply call it like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](Surname) LIKE 'OREILLY%'
```

If you don't want spaces, just change it to: `'%[^a-z0-9]%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a function to split:

```
create function [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

Use this in you where clause:

```
WHERE ((REPLACE(Surname, items, '') FROM dbo.Split('/,?,^,{,},[,],;,$,=,*,#,|,&,@,\,<,>,(,),+,.')) LIKE 'OREILLY%')
```

Answer (score 0):

General approach - yes.

- Make another field (NameNormalized)
- Run a trigger that sets the field whenever the name is updated.
- Then you can run a search on that field (which can have an index).

Bascially the whole replace orgy makes the whole thing non-indexable, so the better approach is to store the normalized value and allow fast lookups.

Oh, and evaluate whether the distinct is needed - that is another hugh slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct Forenames, Surname, dbUSNs.DateOfBirth, Datasetname, 
       dbUSNs.MoPIGrade, SourceAddress, VRM, URNs 
FROM Person 
WHERE Surname LIKE 'O[/?^{}[];$=*#|@\<>()+.]R[/?^{}[];$=*#|@\<>()+.]E[/?^{}[];$=*#|@\<>()+.]I[/?^{}[];$=*#|@\<>()+.]L[/?^{}[];$=*#|@\<>()+.]L[/?^{}[];$=*#|@\<>()+.]Y%')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all special characters just using SUB STRING and While

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100),@Len INT,@Pos INT = 1,@char char(1),@results varchar(100)
SET @str = 'O''Rielly la/.das.d,as/.d,a/.da.sdo23eu89038 !£$$'
SET @Len = LEN(@str)
Set @results = ''
WHILE @Pos < @Len
BEGIN 
SET @char = SUBSTRING(@str,@Pos,1)
IF @char like '[a-z0-9]' or @char = ' '
BEGIN
SET @results = @results + @char
END
SET @Pos = @Pos + 1
END
select @results
```